# Access - Excel(VBA) - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, time-and-attendance

We're trying to load data from Access Database using VBA to Excel. But our code doesn't work fine.

```
SQL1 = "SELECT Name " & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "FROM February" & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "WHERE Gender = 'F'" & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "ORDER BY Name"
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL1, dbOpenSnapshot)

 If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data retrieved from database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Data"
     GoTo SubExit
 Else
     rs1.MoveLast
     recCount = rs1.RecordCount
     rs1.MoveFirst
End If
  xlSheet.Range("B28").CopyFromRecordset rs1
```

We're getting an error of "Type Mismatched" in the line:

```
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL1, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Can anyone help us and explain us why we're getting that error?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, does not how you've declared your variable (or if they are not explicitly declared in which case they should be by having an `Option Explicit` at the top, nor how you initialize the database. For all I can see, `db` is undeclared. Furthermore, I don't know whether `rs1` is implicitly declared as `ADODB.Recordset`, which would be a mismatch since `Database.OpenRecordset()` can only return a `DAO.Recordset`.

Comment: Part of problem is lack of spaces at ends of FROM and WHERE lines building the SQL statement. Text is 'running together'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL1 = "SELECT Name " & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "FROM February" & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "WHERE Gender = 'F'" & _
SQL1 = SQL1 & "ORDER BY Name"
```

should be

```
SQL1 = " SELECT Name " & _
       " FROM February" & _
       " WHERE Gender = 'F'" & _
       " ORDER BY Name"
```

...or don't use the line continuation and use `SQL1 = SQL1 &`, but you can only use *one* of those options.